# Replace cell values in dataframe1 with previously determined values in dataframe2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like.
data1 = 
ID  A  B  C  D  O
T1  1  3  3  2  1
T2  2  4  2  3  0
T3  4  1  1  4  0
T4  5  2  4  5  0
T5  3  5  5  1  1

And other data is.

data2 =

bin  A     B     C     D
1    0.2   0.1   0.3   0.4
2    0.1   0.3   0.7   0.9
3    0.5   0.7   0.8   1.0
4    0.15  0.25  0.91  0.71
5    0.35  0.05  0.71  0.58

I want to replace the columns A,B,C,D values in data1 with the bin values in data2, so that the final data looks like below.

data1_updated =

ID   A     B     C     D      O
T1   0.2   0.7   0.8   0.9    1
T2   0.1   0.25  0.7   1.0    0
T3   0.15  0.1   0.3   0.71   0 
T4   0.35  0.2   0.91  0.58   0
T5   0.5   0.5   0.71  0.4    1

How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can do column update like this:

```
>>> data1[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] = data2[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
>>> data1
   ID     A     B     C     D  O
0  T1  0.20  0.10  0.30  0.40  1
1  T2  0.10  0.30  0.70  0.90  0
2  T3  0.50  0.70  0.80  1.00  0
3  T4  0.15  0.25  0.91  0.71  0
4  T5  0.35  0.05  0.71  0.58  1
```